# Bubble up Fault message from Flow to edit screen instead of the generic message

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow

I know how to trap error faults in a flow and send the details in an email.  What I can't figure out is how to send the fault message details back to the edit screen that caused the actual fault.  I have a process builder/e setup to modify another object when the first object is changed.  Currently the screen shows a message that the process builder failed due to an error in the flow interview but only the error id is displayed.  I would like to include minimally the fault message and possibly additional data.  Is there any way to pass the enhance the response from the flow?

Comment: You have a record-triggered flow that causes an update on a related object and the error is coming from the related object's process builder? It sounds like there is a DML error in the process builder that you _could_ catch in a fault path, but I am not sure there's a way to have this fault continue to bubble up to the source of the record-triggering operation.

Comment: Not completely correct.  The process builder triggers a flow which updates the related object.  The fault comes from an invalid data combination caught by a validation rule on the related object.  I would like the message from the validation rule to bubble up to the page layout.